# git recognize file out .git folder

Tags: git, status

when I run git status -s, git recognize file out of where .git folder.

```
paganotti:test paganotti$ pwd
/Users/paganotti/Documents/Project/prova/test

paganotti:test paganotti$ git status -s
M ../.DS_Store
M cambiato
```

the repository is "test" folder not "prova"! and .git folder is inside a "test" folder

Why git see ../.DS_Store that it is outside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you type git rm --cached ../.DS_Store  it should untrack the file from later commits. Try it and see if it's removed when you do git status -s

Hope that helps,

-Wes

More info @ http://help.github.com/ignore-files/

Comment: Hi, git rm --cached ../.DS_Store not remove file. I obtain fatal: '../.DS_Store' is outside repository

Comment: Try removing the .DS_Store file from /Users/paganotti/Documents/Project/prova/ it will regenerate another but might resolve the git issue. Type rm -rf .DS_Store when you are inside the /Users/paganotti/Documents/Project/prova/ directory. Then try to git status -s and see if that works.

Comment: I remove it. then git status -s output this:  D ../.DS_Store So, I exec git add -u for adjust index, then git commit -m 'dadas'. Now it is disappear. thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem. Just make sure that doesn't "A ../.DS_Store" because if it re-adds it...you could run into that issue again.